# Unwanted canvas title in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgsmapcanvas, title

The main map canvas shows a plain text title or label at the top left. It behaves like a decoration from View > Decorations but it is not accessible from there. The text is relevant to the project, so I have entered it sometime somewhere but can now find no dialog in any settings or properties to disable or edit it. Where, besides View > Decorations is a canvas title accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the author's comment here so this question is answered:

> it was a text Annotation, a QGIS feature I was not familiar with and must have entered more-or-less by accident.